# Is there a way to detect when core data is ready?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I would like to know if there is a way to detect whether or not Core Data is ready to execute requests. What I am currently noticing in my project is that after successfully switching between PSCs and managedObjectContexts, if I perform a fetch request immediately, coredata only returns a portion of the expected records. Give it a few more seconds and it will return all of it on the next fetch.

Ex.
Coredata has 5 records of entity A

1. Switch PSC/managedObjectContext
2. Immediately fetch # of records in entity A
3. Coredata returns 3 records
4. Fetch again
5. Coredata returns all 5

Comment: In Core Data, when you create the MOC,DataModel and PSC, you should use lazy initialization. This means they will be ready. Other things you could use Observes. (KVO or NSNotificationCenter)

Comment: I appreciate your recommendation, but my problem still stays as the scenario is I need to ensure the MOC, DataModel and PSC to be ready before I progress.

Comment: If(myManagedObjectContext){. // do you need, Your MOC is available }

Comment: Why are you "switching" persistent store coordinators? Could you explain? Can you post information about your fetch request?

Comment: I am switching due to a need from our architectural design decision. The decision was that each user would have their own sqlite file since each user's information was not related to each other. This would also make it easier when we needed to remove specific user information from the device. The query I am performing is a simple fetch all records from a certain entity.

Comment: Show the code you use for switching and then querying. Try it in a (minimal) new project and see if the result is the same.

Comment: CoreData is ready just after all moc, psc and mom are initialized - there is no any delay. Enable coredata debug and check sql statements.